# selectively log requests using logging module

Tags: python, python-2.7

All the requests and responses are logged in a web framework, but it is logging(using the logging module) in passwords also (because passwords are in login requests).

Can i selectively print 'XXXXXXX' for password or any other fields i dont wish to print?

in authentication.py

```
import logging
from logging import config
logging.config.dictConfig({'version': 1, 'delete_existing_loggers': False, 'handlers': '.....'})

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

##code to get variables from http request packet (like method, parameters)(for example, methods, params can be: [authentication.login, username, password], [authentication.change_password, username, old_password, new_password], [authentication.generate_validation_code, username]),
LOGGER.info('method %s with %s parameters called', method, params)
```

so here i want, for specific methods, some variables should be 'xxxxx' instead of original value, specifically if the method is 'authentication.login'  I want to print 'xxxx' for second parameter in the params.

Thanks.

Comment: It's best to sanitize data at the application level, before you pass it down to the logging module. Of course, you could write some custom formatter that removes sensitive information, but that would be hard to maintain and it might not be 100% effective.

Comment: Try submitting password data using POST instead of GET

Comment: @SpoonMeiser this at the middleware where the requests are processed after variables are stripped out of http request. So will not work.

Comment: I don't understand. Please can you elaborate in the question; show us the code that does the logging, some example output or something?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I have edited the question with some code.

Comment: @Unknown, yes, i had to retort to sanitize data before logging as it is creating too much coupling between modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Take a look at the [`logging.Filter` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects). You need to subclass it and then register it with your logger.

Example:

```
class PasswordLoggingFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        # Modify record, especially record.msg and/or record.args.
        if want_to_keep_record:
            return True
        else:
            return False

logger.addFilter(PasswordLoggingFilter())
```

For the details of the `record` object, it's [documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects).

Comment: Can you please tell if the parameters that we give in logger.info(msg, a, b) will a, b be available in record in filter function? I have tried it and by the time control reaches filter function, there seems to be no other arguments (a, b)

Comment: The ``record`` argument for the ``filter()`` function is an object of class ``LogRecord`` ([see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects). ``record.msg`` contains the original message string, ``record.args`` contains the arguments.

Comment: Thanks its working. Initially it did not work because in the dictConfi i passed handlers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to solution provided by Christian, if handlers are passed in dictConfig or fileConfig, handler classes should be subclassed and filters need to be added.

Code is taken from following web page:
http://streamhacker.com/2010/04/08/python-logging-filters/

```
class InfoFilter(logging.Filter):
def filter(self, rec):
    return rec.levelno == logging.INFO

class InfoHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.addFilter(InfoFilter())
```

In addition if one wants to change record's arg field, one has to take it into a list and then change it and reassign it back.